# Перевод пиксельных координат в мировые

Tags: python, opencv

Работаю на языке ***Python*** и использую библиотеку ***OpenCV***. У меня есть прямоугольный маркер и камера, размеры маркера известны. Камера откалибрована, есть матрица калибровка и коэффициенты дисторсии. Далее я определяю сам маркер в видео потоке и пиксельные координаты его углов. 
А дальше у меняя какой-то затуп, совершенно не могу понять, как перевести пиксельные координаты углов в мировые, относительно камеры (X,Y,Z). Мне подсказали вывести четыре уравнения в систему и найти какие постоянные по методу Гауса, но уже неделю сижу, а толковой информации в интеренте найти не могу, буду очень благодарен за конструктивный и понятный ответ.
Камера является начальной точкой отчета в 3-х мерном пространстве (0,0,0)

Comment: Никак. Нельзя из двух координат вывести три.

Comment: А как тогда вывести 2? Буду очень признателен, если вы поможете :)

Comment: В общем случае тоже никак.